# How can we call Rest Service before birt Preview

Tags: java, birt

My Rptdesign files are hosted in another machine which can be download by Rest Call. When i tried preview from birt using frameset its using local machine to lookup the report. How can we call rest service to download the file before preview was requested by the clinet.